# Merge data in Salesforce Apex

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

*I need to make a merge data method in salesforce apex, i have many accounts and I want to copy the contacts from one account to another. Is it possible to do it?*

**Can someone help me out with this, please?**

Thanks in advance. [IMAGE PREVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udMye.jpg)
This is the visualpage I just develop, I need to select one, two or three and copy the contacts to another.

Comment: No body knows? Is my question so hard?

Comment: Suppose Account A1 have contact C1 and C2 and Account A2 have contact C3
If you want to move C1 and C2 into account A2, you just need to change accountid of Contact C1 and C2.

Comment: Yes, how code that in apex? I have the method in a class. In a apex class I did successfully? How can I build that in visualforce page?

Comment: On a contrary, your question is very basic for Salesforce Developers. It seemed that you even haven't tried to google the question you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run method from class in your Visualforce's controller or extension. please check [How To: Call Apex code from a Custom Button](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/)